# CTA Button design with HTML

Tags: html, css

I'm hoping you can help me. The [CTA Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPCpP.jpg) I use for my emails is currently clickable only if you click on the text. I' m trying to make the whole box clickable.

The current HTML Code for my CTA Button is:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="button" style="border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;" width="100%">
    <tbody class="button">
        <tr>
            <td align="center" class="button" style="padding:10px 50px; mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;" valign="top">
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="button" style="border-collapse: separate !important;border: 0px none;border-radius: 7px;background-color: #cb673d;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;" width="100%">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" class="button" style="font-family: verdana;font-size: 12px;padding: 15px;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;" valign="middle"><a class="button" href="*http://www.mywebsite.com*" style="font-weight: bold;letter-spacing: .5px;line-height: 100%;text-align: center;word-wrap: break-word;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;text-decoration:none;color: #EFEFEF;" target="_blank">Submit your application</a></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

What should I change in order to have the whole CTA Button clickable?
Thank you very much in advance for your help.

Lucile

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this:

```html
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="button" style="border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;" width="100%">
    <tbody class="button">
        <tr>
            <td align="center" class="button" style="padding:10px 50px; mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;" valign="top">
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="button" style="border-collapse: separate !important;border: 0px none;border-radius: 7px;background-color: #cb673d;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;" width="100%">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="center" class="button" style="font-family: verdana;font-size: 12px;padding: 15px;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;padding: 0;" valign="middle"><a class="button" href="*http://www.mywebsite.com*" style="font-weight: bold;letter-spacing: .5px;line-height: 100%;text-align: center;word-wrap: break-word;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;text-decoration:none;color: #EFEFEF;display: block;width: 100%;height: 100%;padding: 15px;text-align:center;" target="_blank">Submit your application</a></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: However, text is no longer centered in the Button. How can I fix this?

Comment: Just added text-align: center to <a> - please copy again and test it

Comment: Still doesnt' t work, the text is now all the way to the right of the Button

Comment: It is working as excpected in code snippet so it looks like the table is overflowing screen size in your case. Please check if there are an elements wider than screen width above or below CTA button in the rest of your code.

Comment: I can' t find any... and the text in the original code was centered... any other solution you could think of?